# Why does perl's unpack() think that the second argument is a string?

Tags: perl, binary

And how do I fix it?

If I do the following:

```
print unpack("B8", 7) . "\n";
```

I get the following output:

```
00110111
```

The expected output is of course 00000111. I've checked, and it's giving me ascii "7", the string. I'm able to fix it poorly by wrapping the 7 in a chr():

```
print unpack("B8", chr(7)) . "\n";
```

Of course, this will only work if my input remains below 255, and I suspect it may go into the low thousands (I'll make the "B8" dynamic too).

I know I'm being obtuse, but I've read the docs on this and they make no mention of it. Its reverse function, pack(), seems to interpret the second argument correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`unpack` unpacks a string of bytes into scalars with the values represented by those bytes.

```
$ perl -E'say for unpack("nB8", "\x12\x34\x56")'
4660
01010110
```

You're looking for

```
sprintf("%08B", 7)
```

Comment: You're quite right... I've been using pack so much here lately I'd gotten tunnel vision. Thank you.